# DigitalOcean Network Firewall allowing SSH connections on ports other than only 22

Tags: ssh, security, firewall, digital-ocean, network-security

I have a droplet on DigitalOcean with IPv4 and IPv6 enabled. The droplet is behind a digital ocean network firewall with the following rules:

Inbound:

- SSH  TCP 22  All IPv4, All IPv6
- HTTP TCP 80  All IPv4, All IPv6
- HTTP TCP 443 All IPv4, All IPv6

Outbound:

- ICMP     ICMP                All IPv4 All IPv6
- All TCP  TCP     All ports   All IPv4 All IPv6
- All UDP  UDP     All ports   All IPv4

My understanding and expectation is that will block all ssh attempts on ports other than port 22. However when checking the sshd unit in systemd journal. I see the following entries:

```
2022-12-29 03:00:32 Disconnected from invalid user antonio 43.153.179.44 port 45614 [preauth]
2022-12-29 03:00:32 Received disconnect from 43.153.179.44 port 45614:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
2022-12-29 03:00:31 Invalid user antonio from 43.153.179.44 port 45614
2022-12-29 02:58:37 Disconnected from invalid user desliga 190.129.122.3 port 1199 [preauth]
2022-12-29 02:58:37 Received disconnect from 190.129.122.3 port 1199:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
2022-12-29 02:58:37 Invalid user desliga from 190.129.122.3 port 1199
```

and many more of these lines, which means the firewall is not blocking ssh connections on ports other than 22.

The following graph shows the number of ssh connections to ports other than 22 in the last hour. The connections are reduced with enabling the Network Filter, but they not diminished.

[image]

Could it be that the Network Firewall of DigitalOcean is broken?

What am I missing?

Anyone is seeing the same situation on their infrastructure?

Comment: That's the **source** port, not the destination port.

Comment: Yes. I misunderstood the log messages. thank you for the comment! very helpful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Services are listening on certain port, e.g. sshd on port 22 by default. It means that if there is ssh client request to establish connection on the port other than 22 it would not be heard by the sshd service at all. There would be no trace in the log file for sshd for this request.
In this case, that requests are actually coming on the port 22.
What does `Invalid user antonio from 43.153.179.44 port 45614` means actually?

1. There was ssh client request to connect as user `antonio`, which does not exist on the system
2. Request came from the IP address `43.153.179.44`
3. Port number of the ssh client used for connection was `45614`, it is the port number on the client side not on your droplet.

> Could it be that the Network Firewall of DigitalOcean is broken?

This is very unlikely.

Comment: Ah that's the port number where the connection was initiated. Very very helpful thank you

Answer (score 7):

First of all, your ssh daemon is not listening on any port but 22. So noone can connect to it on a port different from port 22. For a connection to succeed, it has to be allowed by firewall, *and* something has to be waiting to receive the packet - listening on the port in tech parlance.

Furthermore, the firewall probably doesn't look at what's inside packets. It goes by port numbers only, and 22 is the reserved port for ssh, so it shows that it allows ssh.

A TCP connection consists of four identifiers:

1. Source IP
2. Source port
3. Destination IP
4. Destination port

The ports and IP shown in your logs is the source IP and source port. These are the so-called [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), that's randomly assigned to a process that wants to make an outgoing connection.

Comment: Ah that's the source port number... not the port number on my droplet...I was misunderstanding the log messages... Very very helpful thank you!